# Android: Unparseable date at ofset 4

Tags: android, date

I am comparing the given `date` with the `current` date but it gives me an error of `Unparseable date at ofset 4`. The date is looks like this `2010-03-25`. This is the line where the logcat pointing me towards `strDate = sdf.parse(item.dateUpdated());`

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/mm/dd");
            Date strDate;
            try {
                strDate = sdf.parse(item.dateUpdated());



                if (System.currentTimeMillis() > strDate.getTime()) {

                    System.out.println("Date not matched");
                }
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: answer is updated please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do it as folows

```
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
            Date strDate;
            try {
                strDate = sdf.parse("2010-03-25");



                if (System.currentTimeMillis() > strDate.getTime()) {

                    System.out.println("Date not matched");
                }
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

as yous `SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/mm/dd");` is having **yyyy/mm/dd** while you are passing as **2010-03-25**

so use    `SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");`

instead of  `SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/mm/dd");`

otherwisely it will say

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2010-03-25"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:357)
```

Comment: I'd assume OP is interested in months and not minutes with `mm`

Comment: Oh my God this is very bad, I even haven't looked at what I am parsing. Thanks for pointing out my mistake

Comment: @laalto i just tested the code in netbeans ide and gave answer, if op will describe or ask  more than answer will be updated accordingly!!

Comment: @user3294034 it happens sometimes, no need to worry!! hope answer is  useful!!